# Show boundary which separate country Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to make map using google map. I want want to show only the boundary which separate the country.

The following image is the result I want:

[image]

The expected result is the following:

[image]

As you can see, I can't figure out how to show the border that separate the country:

Here my custom style that I use to get the second screenshot:

```
[{
  elementType: "geometry",
  stylers: [{
    color: "#cbdddd"
  }]
},
{
  elementType: "labels.icon",
  stylers: [{
    visibility: "off"
  }]
},
{
  elementType: "labels.text.fill",
  stylers: [{
    color: "#616161",
    visibility: "off"
  }]
},
{
  elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
  stylers: [{
    color: "#f5f5f5",
    visibility: "off"
  }]
},
{
  featureType: "poi.park",
  elementType: "geometry",
  stylers: [{
    visibility: "off"
  }]
}, 
{
  featureType: "water",
  elementType: "geometry",
  stylers: [{
    color: "#f2f6f7"
  }]
},
{
  featureType: "administrative",
  elementType: "labels",
  stylers: [{
    visibility: "off"
  }]
},
{
  featureType: "poi",
  elementType: "labels",
  stylers: [{
    visibility: "off"
  }]
},
{
  featureType: "water",
  elementType: "labels",
  stylers: [{
    visibility: "off"
  }]
}]
```

My question is, what is the style that show thoses borders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added thoses lines:

```
{
     featureType: "administrative.country",
     elementType: "geometry.stroke",
     stylers: [{
        color: '#ffffff'
     }]
}
```

After reading these tutorials and APIs:

- [Styling map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple?hl=en)
- [Styling Element](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference?hl=en#style-elements)

I got the wanted result.

[image]

Here the full style:

```
[{
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
            color: "#cbdddd"
        }]
    },
    {
        featureType: "poi.park",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "off"
        }]
    }, {
        featureType: "water",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
            color: "#f2f6f7"
        }]
    }, {
        featureType: "administrative",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "off"
        }]
    }, {
        // I added those line
        featureType: "administrative.country",
        elementType: "geometry.stroke",
        stylers: [{
            color: '#ffffff'
        }]
    }, {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "off"
        }]
    }, {
        featureType: "water",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "off"
        }]
    }
]
```